# SQL two WHERE conditions for the same column

Tags: sql

i have tried to get **Essn** values from the table below from only those who work in **Pno** 3 but not in 10

So the result woud be `"666884444"`

I tried to do it like

```
SELECT Essn
FROM WORKS_ON 
WHERE Pno = 3 and Pno != 10;
```

But cant get the right result

WORKS_ON

```
---Essn-----------Pno-----------Hours----
"123456789"       "1"           "32.5"
"123456789"       "2"           "7.5"
"666884444"       "3"           "40"
"453453453"       "1"           "20"
"453453453"       "2"           "20"
"333445555"       "2"           "10"
"333445555"       "3"           "10"
"333445555"      "10"           "10"
"333445555"      "20"           "10"
"999887777"      "30"           "30"
"999887777"      "10"           "10"
"987987987"      "10"           "35"
"987987987"      "30"           "5"
"987654321"      "30"           "20"
"987654321"      "20"           "15"
"888665555"      "20"           NULL
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I don't think I understand how the value of one column could be both 3 and 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your WHERE-Condition doesn't work because it's only comparing the values of each row separately.
There are many ways to achieve this, this is my first idea:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Essn
FROM WORKS_ON 
WHERE Pno = 3 AND Essn NOT IN (SELECT Essn FROM WORKS_ON WHERE Pno = 10);
```

Comment: This, except `Pno` seems to be a string, not a number

Comment: Yea, depends on RDBMS. On SQL Server it'd work (implicit conversion)

Comment: sure, but we still don't know that, so itmay not work for other dbms

Answer (score 0):

I think you an do what you want with `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT Essn
FROM WORKS_ON 
GROUP BY Essn
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Pno = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND   -- has 3
       SUM(CASE WHEN Pno = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;     -- does not have 10
```

Comment: I dont think this will work, OP **seems** to have strings not integers.

Comment: @Perse-Fisher . . . If the values are strings, then use single quotes for the `WHEN` comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Essn
FROM WORKS_ON 
WHERE Pno = "3"
```

This itself returns `Essn` of only the `Pno` column has value of 3.

Why do you need another `WHERE Pno != 10`.